# Issue while inserting data from modal - PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, modal-dialog

I hope everyone is doing well here.

So, Basically, I was working on a modal for my portal, and the conflicting thing is that. Whenever I - Someone tries to fill and Submit the form together. It just sends a single person's data - Into MySQL.

What I have already tried.

1. Insert a dummy data click to open the modal and Update on the submit button - Delete on the Cancel button.
   [image]

The problem I'm facing while using the upper mentioned idea. The query deletes all the dummy values.
I can't find a way to delete the data with the same id or something.

This query is for getting the max receipt no. and Putting that value on the input field to show on the modal form - That this is the receipt no. You're filling.

```
$query = "select MAX(Receipt_no) from payments";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$receipt_no = $row['MAX(Receipt_no)']+1;
$inputterr = $_SESSION['name'];
```

The second query is creating dummyvalue/ Slot for the users who will take fees. I did this to prevent duplicate entries at the same time.

```
$query_ru = "insert into payments(id,amount,remarks,receipt_no,full_name,fee_head,payment_mode,timings,inputter,amount_in_words,Month_Of_Payment,cheque_no,ef_no,FEE_TYPE) 
values(Null,000000,'dummyvalue','$receipt_no','Fee in Process.','dummyvalue','dummyvalue','dummyvalue','$inputterr','dummyvalue','','dummyvalue','dummyvalue','Fee in process.')";
$exec_tu = mysqli_query($conn,$query_ru);
```

The below query will update the data of that slot which is made on click to the modal.

```
 $x_id = $_GET['id'] ?? '';

    $ef_no = $_POST['ef_no'];
    $receipt_no1 = $_POST['receipt_no'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $remarks = $_POST['remarks'];
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $fee_head = $_POST['fee_head'];
    $cheque_no = $_POST['cheque_no'];
    $payment_mode = $_POST['payment_mode'];
    $timings = $_POST['timings'];
    $amount = $_POST['amount'];
    $FEE_TYPE = $_POST['FEE_TYPE'];
    $inputter = $_POST['inputter'];
    $amount_in_words = $_POST['amount_in_words'];
    $receiving_date11 = $_POST['date'];
    $rec_date = date("d-M-Y",strtotime($receiving_date11));
    $month_of_payment = $_POST['month_of_payment'];
    $mop = date('y-m-d',strtotime($month_of_payment));


    $query_t = "update payments set amount='$amount',ef_no='$ef_no',remarks='$remarks',FULL_NAME='$name',FEE_HEAD='$fee_head',PAYMENT_MODE='$payment_mode',AMOUNT_IN_WORDS='$amount_in_words',Month_Of_Payment='$mop',CHEQUE_NO='$cheque_no',TIMINGS='$timings',INPUTTER='$inputter',FEE_TYPE='$FEE_TYPE' where id='$x_id'";
    $exec_t = mysqli_query($conn,$query_t);
```

The same thing is happening on the Cancel button that deletes the row data created when the modal is opened.

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
                        <br>
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="BtnSave">
                        <!-- <button class="2 btn btn-danger" name="CancelBtn">Cancel</button> -->
                        <?php
                        // echo "<a href='deleteDummy.php?id=$hidden_id' class='2 btn btn-danger'>Cancel</a>";
                        echo "<a href='deleteDummy.php?id=$hidden_id'><button type='button' class='btn btn-danger' >Cancel</button></a>";
                         ?>
                    </div>
```

Problem(2) I blocked refresh on that form as If someone refreshes that form, It doesn't not deletes from the table and Stays remains forever.
[image]

Well, I'm looking forward to someone's help. I would appreciate that!

I appreciate any help you can provide.
Best,
Taha

Comment: You put quite some effort into this question, but it is unclear what problem you're having, or how we can help. Putting [code in an image is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Comment: Hi @KIKOSoftware,
Thank you for approaching. 

So, Let me explain more deeply and Put the code here also. 

I had developed a portal for my institute on PHP and MySQL. And The portal is getting used by many staff/users - Role. Also, Admin.

Comment: Hi, 
I have edited the post and Added the code to that. And Elaborate on the problem I'm facing right now. 

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you. I read your question again, but I still have trouble understanding it. Perhaps someone else can make more sense of it than I can? One thing that people will remark upon is that you don't use [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php), this is a big security risk.

Comment: Thank you. Ok, So I think the better way is to define my problem a little bit more deeply. 
So, As you can see in the first image, there is an input field of Receipt No. What I'm doing on that Is I'm running the query to get the max Receipt No. And Than Plus 1 on to that. And Show that on the Modal. The Input field. The Receipt No. 
Everything is good until there, But Now. If someone opens the same modal, It fetches the same Receipt No. And Show on the Form. That's the start of the problem. 
The Receipt No. is Unique Key, and Duplicate entries are not acceptable.

Hope you got my point.

Comment: I have tried to resolve this issue Whenever someone opens a modal. It creates a row a Dummyvalue row. Which will be updated on the submit and Deleted on the cancel button. Both codes are attached to the top.

Comment: I don't think you're using the right approach here. Creating a "Receipt No" before actually inserting it, runs the risk of getting duplicates. Databases can easily work with unique numbers for records if you use an [AUTO_INCREMENT](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/auto_increment.php) column.